# Retrieving static property value with InvokeMember

Tags: c#, reflection

The following piece of code fails with:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'TestApp.Example.Value' not found.

I also tried changing `BindingFlags.Static` into `BindingFlags.Instance` and passing an actual instance as the fourth parameter but with the same results.
Is there any way I can fix this?

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var flags = BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
            var value = typeof(Example).InvokeMember("Value", flags, null, null, null);
        }
    }

    public sealed class Example {
        public static readonly string Value = "value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Example.Value` is a field, not a method. Use this instead:

```
var value = typeof(Example).GetField("Value").GetValue(null);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dumb question. I was under the impression that the member was a property. I will accept this as the answer as soon as the site allows me to do so (it says 5 minutes).

Comment: Properties are defined with get and/or set methods: `public static string Value { get { return "value"; } }`. And don't worry, there are no _dumb_ questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for FieldInfo, example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)

```
class MyClass
{
    public static String val = "test";
    public static void Main()
    {
        FieldInfo myf = typeof(MyClass).GetField("val");
        Console.WriteLine(myf.GetValue(null));
        val = "hi";
        Console.WriteLine(myf.GetValue(null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a field so you want to use a combination of `GetField` and `GetValue` vs. `InvokeMember`

```
var value = typeof(Example).GetField("Value", flags).GetValue(null);
```